# code to list the content of zipped text files in cmd or SAS ?

Tags: cmd, sas

code to list the content of zipped text files in cmd or SAS ? There are so many answer, but no one exactly pointing to this question. Without downloading any other .exe or installing package file. Please help thanks.

Comment: What have you tried or considered so far?

Comment: Did you already have a look at [this](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2016/03/04/add-files-to-a-zip-archive-with-filename-zip/)?

Comment: What version of SAS?  The latest version includes the ZIP filename engine. What operating system?  If you have the unzip program on Unix then the command `unzip -Z` will show the contents of a zip file.

Comment: This is unclear to me. Are you wanting a list of the files stored in the archive or the content of one or more of the files in the archive?

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2017/09/08/filename-zip-details/

Comment: Link above has full macro/code to list files in a zip file, assuming that it's been created with WinZip.

Answer (score 0):

A zip file is an aggregate storage location, much like a regular folder is.  The statement `INFILE aggregate-fileref FILENAME=` option will deliver the current aggregrate items name.  However, it appears the ZIP filename engine does not honor this convention.  Regardless, you can still access all the contents of each file in the zip.

Create a zip file with two members:

```
filename archive ZIP "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))\testzip.zip";

%put NOTE: Archive file is %sysfunc(pathname(archive));
%put NOTE: Delete archive, rc=%sysfunc(fdelete(archive));

data _null_;
  file archive(one.txt);
  put 'i'; do i = 1 to 10; put i; end;
data _null_;
  file archive(two.txt);
  put 'z'; do z = 10 to 20; put z; end;
run;
```

Create two text files in a regular folder (they will be used to contrast aggregate input from ZIP and OS folder):

```
filename folder "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))";
data _null_;
  file folder(one.txt);
  put 'i'; do i = 1 to 10; put i; end;
data _null_;
  file folder(two.txt);
  put 'z'; do z = 10 to 20; put z; end;
run;
```

Read from multiple files in the regular folder using aggregate syntax.  Notice how the filename is logged:

```
data _null_;
  length filename $250;
  infile folder(*.txt) filename=filename;  * specify which aggregate members to process; 
  input;
  if filename ne lag(filename) then put 'NOTE: ' filename=;
  put _infile_;
run;

----- LOG -----
NOTE: filename=C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary Files\_TD24468_HELIUM_\one.txt
i
1
2
...
NOTE: filename=C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary Files\_TD24468_HELIUM_\two.txt
z
10
11
```

Now read from zip as an aggregate.  Unfortunately the filename value does not change when the ZIP engine moves to the next member in the zip.  Regardless, you still get the contents:

```
data _null_;
  length filename $250;
  infile archive(*.txt) filename=filename; 
  input;
  if filename ne lag(filename) then put 'NOTE: ' filename=;
  put _infile_;
run;

----- LOG -----
NOTE: filename=C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Temp\SAS Temporary Files\_TD24468_HELIUM_\testzip.zip
i
1
...
10
z
10
...
20
NOTE: A total of 23 records were read from the infile library ARCHIVE.
```

If you need to get a list of the member names in the zip file, in Windows, with no other installation there are `powershell` solutions, and within SAS you can also perform `Proc GROOVY` to run java code that processes a zip file.  In a locked down server environment both of these approaches would not be available as they are deemed external agents that pose a security risk or unmonitored server resource use.